# Typing a TypeScript interface key with pre-set keys

Tags: typescript

so I have this interface:

```
export interface IBlockLabels {
  [name: string]: {
    id: string;
    component: any;
    types;
    name;
  };
}
```

But I would like to be able to have auto completion for [name: string] 
this is my data structure set for IBlockLabels :

```
export const BlockLabels: IBlockLabels = {
  BLOCKCODE_SCENE: {id: '3510', component: BlockSceneComponent, name: 'Scene', types: []},
  RSS: {id: '3345', component: BlockRssComponent, name: 'Rss', types: []},
  LABEL: {id: '3241', component: BlockLabelComponent, name: 'Label', types: []},
  CLOCK: {id: '3320', component: BlockClockComponent, name: 'Clock', types: []},
  IMAGE: {id: '3130', component: BlockImageComponent, name: 'Image', types: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'swf']},
  VIDEO: {id: '3100', component: BlockVideoComponent, name: 'Video', types: ['flv', 'mp4', 'm4v']},
  PLAYLIST: {id: '4102', component: BlockPlaylistComponent, name: 'Playlist', types: []},
  WEATHER: {id: '6010', component: null, name: 'Weather', types: []}
};
```

So it would be awesome if I could get a inference for `[name: string]:` so it can only be of type `RSS or BLOCKCODE_SCENE or LABEL` etc...

I tried to play around with:

```
export type Obj = {
  [key in keyof ListOfMethods]: any
}
```

but to no avail...
Basically I wanted to have 'key' auto completion in my IBlockLabels which with the proper key name and to continue after with completion for the rest of the Object `id, component...`

Thanks,

Sean.

Added:

The solution is:

```
type IBlockLabels = {
    BLOCKCODE_SCENE?: BlockLabelProp;
    RSS?: BlockLabelProp;
    LABEL?: BlockLabelProp;
    CLOCK?: BlockLabelProp;
    IMAGE?: BlockLabelProp;
    VIDEO?: BlockLabelProp;
    PLAYLIST?: BlockLabelProp;
    WEATHER?: BlockLabelProp;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, do you want something like this?

```
type BlockNames = "BLOCKCODE_SCENE" | "RSS" | "LABEL" | "CLOCK" |
    "IMAGE" | "VIDEO" | "PLAYLIST" | "WEATHER"
interface BlockLabelProp {
    id: string;
    component: any; // make this better
    name: string;
    types: string[];
}
type IBlockLabels = Record<BlockNames, BlockLabelProp>;
```

That evaluates to

```
/*
type IBlockLabels = {
    BLOCKCODE_SCENE: BlockLabelProp;
    RSS: BlockLabelProp;
    LABEL: BlockLabelProp;
    CLOCK: BlockLabelProp;
    IMAGE: BlockLabelProp;
    VIDEO: BlockLabelProp;
    PLAYLIST: BlockLabelProp;
    WEATHER: BlockLabelProp;
}
*/
```

which you could have written out yourself if you wanted, but the `Record<K, V>` syntax (or the equivalent `{[P in K]: V}` mapped type syntax) saves you from typing out `BlockLabelProp` a lot.

Anyway that seems to match the type of your `BlockLabels` constant and should give you the IntelliSense hinting you're looking for.

Hope  that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gIQksA1gMpggogDCSAtgA6pkYBc8UKAngNwBQoksCZOiy58BAEpo0VOgxTNWHHn2hxEqTDjyEAMlABGICDPrl5LNl17hVgjSO0EKjk3IWXlNgeuFaxASWooAHNKGlNGCyVrfjUhTVFCADUAS1AkVzN3aJVveIcxAAVodggUzEzIxStuDHZaBESCADkoahA0eABeeAAibB0AeQoAaQpBgBEAUQB9Igop5qne+AAfPvEiIhX13p0AQWwpnR2+iiHRne54G77-AFl9gHFltb6k-2nB097Cg4BNHT+IgAFR+AHUpvsQQAJKbiXrcFLyEAwABmUFIfl0BiMhRgSFo8AA3tdbmkWJgYMjgjxbupZFkolx4AB6VnwIIEBAYAAW5XghgwGFRZJuKDaIEpGGpKFpYvgdQaaGlsuCAG0ALo8AC+tXqCH8TT0hggnR64nASBgwAAPE1Wu00AAabEEE14gm0AB8PFZACp9Q14EbHB6zd0SQqBsMxpNZvNFlMWMbcRB8YS6bdNkQU2G0xnaFmbgcjjo82Jw4Xi-BzrGKzjTdWFQ9nsm3VWvTWPl8G+6C12FX99oDgSC+53MwrIdC4eIJwOp3r-azuNwQAAPegwLD5DtplUh1Om81R+kx0bjaZzBZLFjE+AU+AAcgAzABWACMAAZn67kIyVRNCQZBhIB8iuhK7QsM+IHkH+ioGoeWrwDqzoKjm96PsAMGvq+AAs74IQBETmG6kjSOEbiQZKMEUQhSodCwKFoQqpbHFhT5vgATPhn7EVRTL7qalQQfAUFSi+4YMUhzGaqh6H0nWoycThL54dxv7-oJQEuC4OliRJMHOGIMnKnJCkto8Lyqbhn6vlpDKkQoTSBCEYHOTR0Evm5oRmUx8Dqs+ABWtDBAhz60HKEWhSA4Wus+aAAO5os+8msfSPZTIMtnqT+jkkW4fapOkokYF5knPiVIBIP5yHPmiEAAG4RXQ+GtfhLXpYptzDqOoK5c+fHftxAngS5jjFFApTlBgZUVTBU0zZgdUWRltwzrC8KDQAbN+P5jc5LAoAArhAEALS+4IgFAfKoqtgXpdwOo8NwQA)

Comment: Thank you, as far as I can tell ```Record<BlockNames, BlockLabelProp>;``` will not work since it will require for all fields to exist (RSS | LABEL ...) only ONE of them will exist per implemented interfaced object. Thus your other solution will work (you right should of thought of that  myself :) ) ... so Record will not work because of the above reason right?

Comment: The written-out form and `Record` form are the same... they all require all the keys to be set.  Not sure where "only one of them will exist per implemented interface object" comes from; your `const BlockLabels` has all of them, so my answer requires all of them.  If you actually want to require just one or at least one, or something, that's more complicated but still possible.  Maybe I didn't understand your question properly?

Comment: I added to my initial question how it should have been (thank to your answer) ... look under "The solution is:" in my question above. Notice I added '?' next to each field. I don't think you can do optional keys with the Record. right?

Comment: You can do `Partial<Record<BlockNames, BlockLabelProp>>`, or the equivalent `{[K in BlockNames]?: BlockLabelProp}`.

Comment: YOU ARE GOOD :) ```export type IBlockLabelsRecord = Partial<Record<BlockNames, BlockLabelProp>>;``` is perfect!!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks jcalz, the correct solution:

```
interface BlockLabelProp {
  id: string;
  component: BlockRssComponent | BlockLabelComponent | BlockSceneComponent | BlockClockComponent | BlockImageComponent | BlockVideoComponent | BlockPlaylistComponent | any;
  name: string;
  types: string[];
}

type BlockNames = "BLOCKCODE_SCENE" | "RSS" | "LABEL" | "CLOCK" | "IMAGE" | "VIDEO" | "PLAYLIST" | "WEATHER";

// magic of TS Partial<Record<...
export type IBlockLabelsRecord = Partial<Record<BlockNames, BlockLabelProp>>;
```